# Send JSON to from Local to Server

Tags: php, json

I have a `.json` file in my `C://` drive, and I want to send it to my web server.

The `.json` already generated.

I have search a lot of articles, but there is no sending from local to web server.

My question is : **How to send/parse `.Json` file from local to server?**

The Json file contains My localhost records, and I want to update to my web database, so I use json to send the data.

We need to send the json file to the web-server, and parse in the web-server? or just parse in the local and send it to the web-server?

I am using PHP to process the json file, because I use PHP to connect with database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this at the moment:

```
wget -q -O - --header='Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
    --post-file=postdata.json --user-agent=wget path-to-my-web-service
```

Once you get it on the server, you can use

```
$my_data = json_decode($_POST['json-data']);
```

assuming you have something like `{"json-data":{"fld1":"val1", "fld2":"val2"}}` in your file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you give me example about the sending file script?.